Is there a way to check for memory leaks in a zig program?
Valgrind is great for C/C++, but I don't believe it works for zig programs. I've tried to use valgrind for zig programs that use std.heap.page_allocator, but it is unable to detect any memory allocations.
Is there a way to check for memory leaks for programs made with zig? Or is there a special way you're supposed to use valgrind with zig?

Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

This isn't a "which tool shall I use?" question. It's a "does a tool exist?" one.

If you use Massif with --pages-as-heap=yes then it will give you an indication (it's a heap profiler rather than leak detector).

And for memcheck to work with this it either needs to be extended to recognize the zig allocation functions (please open an item at https://bugs.kde.org preferably with some small examples, simple and clear instructions on how to use zig for non-zig users and if possible some link to the zig mangling scheme). Otherwise you need to annotate the alloctors which can be done using Valgrind client requests.

The zig standard library's GeneralPurposeAllocator automatically checks for leaks (when .deinit() is called). Also, when writing tests, using std.testing.allocator automatically checks for leaks. To use valgrind, you need to link libc and use std.heap.c_allocator.

@PaulFloyd That is essentially the same question...

@PaulFloyd thank you for your suggestions as well as you last comment.
